# When was the last/prior time a former PM served in another (non-PM) position in the UK government?

Tags: united-kingdom, government, history, prime-minister

[CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/11/13/uk/suella-braverman-leaves-government-rishi-sunak-gbr-intl/index.html):

> Sunak then announced he was bringing Cameron back to frontline politics as foreign secretary, in a stunning move that has few parallels in recent British political history.
>
> Cameron served as prime minister from 2010 to 2016, resigning after Britain voted to leave the European Union in a referendum that he had called.

So we're told that kind of move--appointing a former PM to a 'mere' minister role-- is uncommon. When was the last/prior time that that happened?

The BBC [has](https://bbc.com/news/uk-politics-67407974) a hint, but is not super explicit:

> It was Lord Cameron's appointment that stunned Westminster and made him the first former prime minister to re-enter government since the 1970s.

So who's that referring to?

Comment: Also interesting perhaps, Cameron is a minister in the Lords, which has some interesting implications for his cross-questioning https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainer/lords-ministers-role-scrutiny

Comment: not really there have been many ministers in the Lords several in the last 15 years

Comment: If you finished reading the CNN article you linked: "In recent decades, the move can only be compared to Alec Douglas-Home – prime minister for a year from 1963 – who returned as foreign secretary in 1970 under Edward Heath’s government."

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The instance in the 1970s was when Alec Douglas-Home came back to serve as Foreign Secretary in the Heath ministry in 1970, just under six years after leaving the office of Prime Minister in 1964 after the Conservative Party lost the General Election.

A [government blog from 2012](https://history.blog.gov.uk/2012/11/01/former-prime-ministers/) puts the number of Prime Ministers returning to government under another at fourteen since the 18th-century; Cameron now makes this fifteen. The blog doesn't provide a list, so the interested reader may find one below.

| Prime Minister | Date left Office | Later Role | Date Rejoined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David Cameron | 13/07/2016 | Foreign Secretary | 13/11/2023 |
| Alec Douglas-Home | 16/10/1964 | Foreign Secretary | 20/06/1970 |
| Neville Chamberlain | 10/05/1940 | Lord President of the Council | 10/05/1940 |
| Ramsay MacDonald | 07/06/1935 | Lord President of the Council | 07/06/1935 |
| Stanley Baldwin | 04/06/1929 | Lord President of the Council | 24/08/1931 |
| Arthur Balfour | 04/12/1905 | First Lord of the Admiralty | 25/05/1915 |
| The Earl Russell | 21/02/1852 | Foreign Secretary | 28/12/1852 |
| The Duke of Wellington | 16/11/1830 | Foreign Secretary | 1834 |
| The Viscount Goderich | 21/11/1828 | Secretary of State for War and the Colonies | 22/11/1830 |
| Henry Addington | 10/05/1804 | Lord President of the Council | 14/01/1805 |
| The Duke of Portland | 18/12/1783 | Home Secretary | 11/07/1794 |
| Lord North | 27/03/1782 | Home Secretary | 02/04/1783 |
| The Duke of Grafton | 28/01/1770 | Lord Privy Seal | 12/06/1771 |
| The Duke of Newcastle | 26/05/1762 | Lord Privy Seal | 1765 |
| The Duke of Devonshire | 29/06/1757 | Lord Chamberlain | 1757 |

Comment: Wasn't Balfour the foreign secretary - he wore the Balfour Declaration in 1917

Comment: @mmmmmm yes, and he was later also Lord President of the Council - I'm going by the first Cabinet-level position they held post-premiership.

Comment: 15 in a little less than 300 years, so a a bit more than once every 20 years.  Or 15 of the 56 distinct PMs since 1721, for a bit better than 25%.  I'd say that makes the OP's "uncommon" a good choice of words, and CNN's characterization a bit sensationalized.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Note that in the quote above, they say _recent_ history. Taking an average obscures the fact that this hasn't happened in more than 50 years (and the time before was 30 years earlier).

Comment: I would say Stanley Baldwin stopped being prime minister on 4 June 1929 (the second of the three times he stopped, but more relevant than 22 January 1924)

Comment: It could be useful to swap the last two columns: this would better highlight the fact that some actually went immediately from PM to another position (Neville Chamberlain, Ramsay MacDonald).